# How to run async functions in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

A nodeJS script. I have a function in it:

```
async myFunc1(a, b, c) {
  //.......
}
```

which returns some value but not `Promise`. I used to run it as this:

```
 let a1 = await myFunc1(1, "fds", 99);
```

Now I need to run dozens of them at the same time, and the input of the amount of them, with the arguments, comes from the user.

```
let lines = readDataFromUserProvidedFile();
for (let i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    //
    //how to run all the myFunc1(...) in parallel??
    //and then print out a result of each?


    //(?)
    myFunc1(lines[i], i, i*2);
}
```

How will I run them in parallel in such a way? And when a subsequent one returns a result, I want to print it right away.

---

For the function it takes around 10 minutes to return a value. It doesn't do calculations, it waits for a result from remote web service.

Comment: `async myFunc1` will return a promise. _"takes around 10 minutes to return a value"_ how?

Comment: What does `myFunc1` do? If it's waiting for some I/O (eg. reading file from disk, making HTTP request, making database query etc.) then all you need to do is call a bunch of them and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them instead of awaiting them individually.

Comment: However, if `myFunc1` is doing a long calculation and blocking the main thread you cannot run them in parallel without using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: @slebetman it waits for a remote web service to reply. Not calculations

Comment: `async` functions are Promise functions, that's the whole point.

Comment: Do you need to print them all at once or is one at a time acceptable?

Comment: @Someone one at a time will be better

Comment: I think `.then` is your best bet. The `Promise` API allows one to attach a function (like a logger) to the end of a Promise without halting the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update 2023-03-16

The `for...await` evaluates from the sequence on each iteration. It will go over the `promises` array sequentially. If the first promise in the array takes 10 minutes and the second promise 5 minutes. It will NOT log the promise that finished in 5 minutes.

To "log-as-you-go" or as the promise finishes. There are a couple of ways of doing that. It will depend on how much control you want in the normal flow of your code.

Your can use `.forEach` + `.then`:

```js
const lines = readDataFromUserProvidedFile();

const promises = lines.map((line, index) => myFunc1(line, index, index * 2));

promises.forEach(promise => {
  promise.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
});
```

You can remove the `.map` and:

```js
const lines = readDataFromUserProvidedFile();

lines.forEach((line, index) => {
  const promise = myFun(line, index, index * 2);
  promise.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
})
```

In this way, it **will be printing a result of each one as it gets resolved -- one by one**.

If you want better control over which promise is resolved, you need to manually manage the state of each promise. `Promise.all` and `Promise.allSettled` will wait until all promises are finished before handing over the control to you/your code. This is not what you want.

The `Promise` object [represents an asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) operation's eventual completion (or failure) and its resulting value. You need to use [async iteration object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_async_iterator_and_async_iterable_protocols) to execute, control and return values from each interaction.

A functional example:

```js
const lines = readDataFromUserProvidedFile();

const promises = lines.map((line, index) => myFun(line, index, index * 2));

for await (const result of execPromises(promises)) {
  console.log (result)
}

console.log("Completed!")
console.log(promises) // => it will be [] because of the mutable process

async function* execPromises(promises) {
  while (promises.length > 0) {
    const [index, value] = await Promise.race(promises.map((promise, index) =>
      promise.then((value) => [index, value])
    ));

    yield value;
    //  mutable process!!!
    promises.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

And because the `Promise` object doesn't have any "state" information, we need to manually use `.map` to tell our code which promise was completed after their `.then`. `Promice.race` will return the first resolved promise and after it is resolved, we use `.splice` to remove it from the array.

All of that because there's no status information "as-you-go" (e.g. while it is being resolved).

Libraries in the JS ecosystem can abstract that away for you and create better solutions using queues.

For example:

- https://github.com/rxaviers/async-pool

#### Original answer

You can create a collection of promises that will be executed in parallel and then iterate-await on the collection:

Pseudo-code:

```js
let lines = readDataFromUserProvidedFile();

const promises = lines.map((line, index) => myFunc1(line, index, index * 2));

// await the resolution of all promises and print the results as they become available
for await (const result of promises) {
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Will it wait for the resolution of **all** the promises and won't print anything untill all of they have resolved? Or will be printing a result of each one as it gets resolved -- one by one?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover these points @ChinChin395

Answer (score 2):

So, promises have 2 parts. Executing them, and awaiting them. Awaiting them means you're attaching a callback to do something when you get a result. Executing them means just "kicking them off"

Your problem is you're using `await`. There's a difference in starting an asynchronous process, and waiting for the result of an asynchronous process. Specifically, you can start an asynchronous process, and hold a reference to it to `await` it later without `await`-ing it immediately.

tl;dr you can still use `async/await`, just kick off all the promises immediately using `.map`:

```
const myFuncToBeCalled = async () => {

   let lines = readDataFromUserProvidedFile();
   const promises = Array.from({length:lines}).map(async (_,i) => {
      try {
         const result = await myFunc1(lines[i], i, i*2);
         console.log(`got result for line ${i}`,result)
         return result
      } catch(err) {
         console.log(`got an error for line ${i}`, err)
      }
   })

   const arrayOfResults = await Promise.all(promises)
   return arrayOfResults


}
```

Comment: You haven't taken into account that the amount of the functions `myFunc1` that'll be run will be unknown beforehand, have you?

Comment: @ChinChin395 - like the edit? Hard to tell without more code

Comment: `Running promises in parallel is easy - just don't await anything.` -- but I also need to print out a result from each function. Therefore, I'll have to wait somehow

Comment: Promises are designed for this exact thing. Using `.then` basically says "Hey! When this is finished, can you do this for me?"

Comment: @ChinChin395 - thanks for the clarifications, removed the edits. `for await...of` is the nicest syntax posted in the other answer. Don't forget your `catch`!